# Reconnect to Beckhoff PLC using pyads

Tags: python, ads, plc

I wrote a GUI in python using Tkinter , in order to write an read variables through ADS by using pyads, from a Beckhoff PLC CX9020.
I tried to disconnected the communication cable between the GUI and a **"pyads.pyads_ex.ADSError: ADSError: timeout elapsed (1861)"** popped up.

I am trying to write a code that checks every ,let's say, one second the ADS communication status and connect or reconnect whenever an ADS communication is established (cable is connected or disconnected).

I have tried to use read_state() method , but that didn't work well.

Do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get the current connection status without trying an actual read/write. There is for example `pyads.Connection.is_open`, but it seems it's simply a flag whether the connection was initialized, and won't become `False` if the connection is lost.

I think you would be best of trying a `read` to a variable you know exists (or doing `read_state` as you mentioned) and catching any raised exceptions, and acting on that.